# How do you compare date objects to strings in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I have an array of dates in this format:

```
date: 2012-01-02,2012-03-17,2012-04-09,2012-05-07,2012-06-04,2012-08-06,2012-10-29,2012-12-25,2012-12-26.
```

I want to compare the dates with today's date, but I need some help.  This is my code.

```
NSArray *date =[dict12 objectForKey:@"ie_date_closed"];
NSLog(@"date:%@",date);
int i=date;
for (i=0; i<6; i++) 
{   
    NSComparisonResult result = [todaydate compare:date[i]];   
    NSLog(@"result:%d",result);
}
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing ?

Comment: i just try this is not working . help me with your code.

Comment: i want to compare nsarray date with today date.

Comment: `int i=date;` what is that piece of code for? you are initializing an integer value with an `NSArray` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code:-

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
for (NSString *arrDt in date){
if ([arrDt isEqualToString:[formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]]){
NSLog(@"Equal Date");}}
```

**Note:- You need to set the dateFormat according to array object dates.**

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code have a look at & try to implement your self using it :

```
for (i=0; i<[date count]; i++)
{
    NSDateformatter *format = Define Your date Format Here
    NSDate yourDate = [format dateFromString:[date objectAtIndex:i]];
    If ([YourDate compare:[NSDate date]] == NSOrderedSame)
    {
        NSLog(@"Both Dates are same");
    }
}
```

Note : I am not giving you whole readymade code but just for a hint so using it you can be able to implement what you want.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 2):

try it

```
 NSDate *firstTime;
    NSDate *nowTime;
   NSDate *localDate = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone   systemTimeZone]];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"YYYY-MM-dd";
    NSString *str = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:localDate];


      NSArray *date =[dict12 objectForKey:@"ie_date_closed"];
      NSLog(@"date:%@",date);
     for (i=0; i<[date count]; i++) 
{   


     NSString *openTime =[NSString stringWithFormate:"%@"[date objectAtindex:i]];
    NSDateFormatter *dateComperFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateComperFormatter1 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone   systemTimeZone]];
    [dateComperFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd"];


    firstTime = [dateComperFormatter1 dateFromString:openTime];
    nowTime = [dateComperFormatter1 dateFromString:str];
    //    NSComparisonResult result;
    //   // has three possible values: NSOrderedSame,NSOrderedDescending, NSOrderedAscending
    //
    //    result = [nowTime compare:firstTime]; // comparing two dates

    NSComparisonResult result = [nowTime compare:firstTime];
  }
```